# PHP - Registering Users to a Database with more fields than are required

Tags: php, mysql

The fields I'm checking for upon registration:

```
if($username&&$email&&$password&&$repeatpassword) { }
```

I have about 10 fields so my registration query looks like this:

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(
    '','$username','','$password','$email','','','','','',''
)");

die ("You have been registered.");
```

When I try to register it tells me I have registered successfully but does not add the user into the database.  The database name and password are correct.

Comment: Try to add `echo mysql_error();` before `die`

Comment: And learn something about proper error handling and SQL (for example. specify the column names you have values for). :)

Comment: If this code is intended to run in production, please, don't. Read on SQL injection attacks for a moment, and you'll certainly see why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL query looks wrong to me, it should be more like:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (ID, Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('$id', '$username', '$password', '$email' )
```

First the colomns, then the values :)

Comment: Well the columns list is unnecessary for as long as you provide values for every column in the table. It is still recommended though, to avoid having to modify the code every time you add a column...

Comment: This will also help if column order changes for some reason, which tends to happen during development.

Comment: Values shouldn't be interpolated directly into statements. Instead, they should be prepared statement parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds much more like a database design issue. Proper table design should have columns that are NOT required during registration marked as **nullable** so that nothing is required in the SQL. In this case, your insert would look something more like this:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$username','','$password','$email')
```

This is still not best case, however. Best case would be something more like the following:

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email) VALUES('$username','$password','$email')
```

which would specify the specific columns you want to insert into, and avoid the unnecessary extra quotes for empty columns you have in place.